# React Route Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`Context.Consumer`)

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I have privateRoute. When user is not signed in or email is not verified, redirect to modal login with warning. it is run by function show modal but i get error.
it is work, by it is show this errror in dev.
in prod i dont get this error.

warning:

> index.js:1 Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering
> a different component (`Context.Consumer`). To locate the bad
> setState() call inside `Context.Consumer`, follow the stack trace as
> described in
> in Route (at PrivateRoute.js:13)
> in PrivateRoute (at App.js:217)
> in Switch (at App.js:196)
> in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
> in BrowserRouter (at App.js:140)
> in div (at App.js:139)
> in App (at src/index.js:11)
> in Provider (at src/index.js:10)

code:

```
  <Route
  {...rest}
  render={(props) =>
    (user && user.providerId && user.providerId !== 'password') ||
    (user &&
      user.providerId &&
      user.providerId === 'password' &&
      user.emailVerified) ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to="/">{setLoginModalShow(true)}</Redirect>
    )
  }
/>
```

how i shoud do this corect
please help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling setLoginModalShow(true) while redirecting, try below method, pass some flag as action while redirecting to homepage and on homepage check for that flag from router and use it to show login modal

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/",
    state: { action:  "showLogin" }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: it works but give the same error.
This warning only appears once in both solutions

Comment: In above solution where do you call setLoginModalShow function ?

Comment: this is run in App.js

Comment: I think as you are calling setstate in app.js while route is redirecting to another component that means home component is rendering when setstate is being called in app.js, can you try caling setstate in home component instead of app.js, or use context api to call setstate calling function from home page component instead of app.js, your modal logic will be in app.js only but it will be called from home component.