# React - Warning: Cannot update a component (`PrivateRoute`) while rendering a different component (`Modules`)

Tags: reactjs, redux

Getting the following error on all child components.

> react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Cannot update a component
> (`PrivateRoute`) while rendering a different component (`Example`). To
> locate the bad setState() call inside `Examples`,

I've found lots of examples of the same error but thus far no solutions
[React Route Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`Context.Consumer`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65370845/react-route-warning-cannot-update-a-component-app-while-rendering-a-differe)
[Can Redux cause the React warning "Cannot update a component while rendering a different component"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286630/can-redux-cause-the-react-warning-cannot-update-a-component-while-rendering-a-d)

The PrivateRoute wraps the component to redirect if not logged in.

```
export default function PrivateRoute() {
  const session: ISessionReducer = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.core.session);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!session.jwt) <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }, [session]);

  return <Outlet />;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because `useEffect` runs after the component is rendered. So what's happening in this case is that your `Outlet` component is getting rendered first before your code in `useEffect` runs. So if the `jwt token` doesn't exist then it will try to redirect but it won't be able to because your `Outlet` will already be rendered by then.

So I can give you the solution of what I use to check if the `jwt token` exist.

1.) I create a custom hook for checking if the `token` exists. 
2.) And then I use that custom hook in my `privateRoute` component to check if the user is loggedIn.

**`useAuthStatus.js`**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const useAuthStatus = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  const [checkingStatus, setCheckingStatus] = useState(true)

  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user?.token) {
      setLoggedIn(true)
    } else {
      setLoggedIn(false)
    }

    setCheckingStatus(false)
  }, [user?.token])

  return { loggedIn, checkingStatus }
}
```

**`PrivateRoute component`**

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuthStatus } from '../../hooks/useAuthStatus'
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress'

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const { loggedIn, checkingStatus } = useAuthStatus()

  if (checkingStatus) {
    return <CircularProgress className='app__modal-loader' />
  }

  return loggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/login' />
}

export default PrivateRoute
```